# How to receive from datagram socket

Tags: android

I'm developing an App it's like voice chat client connects to server and then voice chat begins.

But server side has problem. The problem is receiving method of datagram socket.

socket.receive();

block waiting for input.

server side :

```
private int channelConfig =  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
AudioRecord recorder;

private boolean status = true;



@SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   }


    receiveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.receive_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    receive_label= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receive_label);
    receiveButton.setOnClickListener(receiveListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
    port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(close);
  //AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   // sampleRate =Integer.parseInt( audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
}

private final OnClickListener close = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
             System.exit(0);
    }

};



private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        status = false;
        speaker.release();
        Log.d("VR","Speaker released.s");

    }

};


private final OnClickListener receiveListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;

        receive_label.setText("socket...2");
        startReceiving();

    }

};

public void startReceiving() {


   final Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {



        @Override
        public void run() {



            try {

                int  minBufSize =4096;//recorder.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat);


                Log.d("VR", ""+channelConfig+"  "+audioFormat+sampleRate);

                  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                  Log.d("VR", "Socket Created.s");


                  byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize+=4096];



                //  for (int sampleRate : new int[] {44100,8000, 11025, 16000 }) {  // add the rates you wish to check against




                      Log.d("bufersize", "bufer size :"+minBufSize);
                      Log.d("bufersize", "bufer size :"+sampleRate);
                      if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {



                          speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*=10,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


                          speaker.play();
                          Log.d("VR", "spekaer playing...");
                      }
                //  }


                  //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                 // int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                      Log.d("VR", ""+status);

                            while(status == true) {

                                  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                                  socket.receive(packet);


                                  Log.d("VR", "Packet Received.s");

                                  //reading content from packet
                                 buffer=packet.getData();
                                  Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer.s");


                                  //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                                  speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                                 Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker.s");
                        }

                        } catch (SocketException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                }


    }); 

 receiveThread.start();
}}
```

client side :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText target,target_port;
private TextView streamingLabel;
private Button startButton,stopButton;
Button button;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private int port=50005;        
AudioRecord recorder;

//AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

private int sampleRate =8000;//=Integer.parseInt(audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       

private boolean status = true;
String size;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    target = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.target_IP);
    streamingLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streaming_label);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    target_port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.target_Port);
    streamingLabel.setText("Press Start! to begin");
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);
    button.setOnClickListener(close);

    target.setText("10.0.2.15");
    target_port.setText("50005");

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  //  sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
   size = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
  //  Log.d("Buffer Size and sample rate", "Size :" + size + " & Rate: " + rate);
}

private final OnClickListener close = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
             System.exit(0);
    }

};



private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released.c");
    }

};




private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }

};



public void startStreaming() {


    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                int minBufSize =AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created.c");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize+=4096];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size .c" + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(target.getText().toString());
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved.c");
                Log.d("VS", size+"");
                if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*=10);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized.c");


                if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)

                    recorder.startRecording();}


                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    //encoding to base64
                 // String buffer1= Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    port=Integer.parseInt(target_port.getText().toString());
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                    socket.send(packet);



                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException message:",e.getMessage().toString());


            } 


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
 }


 }
```

please give me your best help

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: The receive method has been designed in that way! It blocks until a datagram is received. What you exactly need?

Comment: i need my App works well. client side connects to server side but dosen't work. u need full code?

Comment: I think I don't have enough time to evaluate your code, but the point is: does your server send something when a client connects to it? If your server does not send some packet, your thread will be blocked waiting for some datas to come.

Comment: client send some packet to server. and server blocks until gets the packets

Comment: Have you added the android.permission.INTERNET to your manifest file?

Comment: How do you get the ip address to connect to?

Comment: about permission yes i have. about ip : i have wifi(Hotspot program) which i connect to it with phone. then i can see connected devices ip

Comment: Ok. You need both client and server connected to the same ip address and port. How does client retrieve server ip address?

Comment: i enter the ip address manualy

Comment: and the ip address does not change? it's statically assigned? are you sure it is the ip address of your server?

Comment: no.why would it change??it's local ip address and i'm sure of server ip address. do you think source code is okay?and problem is another thing?

Comment: You have a client and a server. The client records some audio and sends packets to a server. The server receives those packets and plays them. Client and server are two Activities and are probably installed in two different devices connected throug a network: that network assign to your client and server two different IP address. How does the client know what is the IP address of the server? Tried binding the datagram server to the IP address you're providing to the client? Use for example the third constructor of DatagramSocket, the one that requires an IP address.

Comment: yes.you explain it perfectly. client doesn't know the ip of server.i cheek the ip in hotspot program( i have installed the program with name hotspot.).it show me every connected device to wifi.  i didn't understand last part of your sentence

Comment: first server takes a port number from text filed and listen on that port. then i put the ip and port in client.so makes connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send and recieve

```
BufferedWriter input;
                while(status == true) {
                  int  bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                      dos.write(buffer,0,bufferReadResult);
                  dos.flush();

                }
```